# Ngrx store take(1), but reset after logout/login

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, store, take

So, imagine you have an ngrx store with a list of books.

When you log in to your profile page you fetch your books using:

```js
this.store.dispatch(getBooks());
```

Which will trigger the effect:

```js
  getBooks$ = createEffect(() =>                                                                 
    this.actions.pipe(                                                                         
      ofType(A.getBooks),                                                                        
      switchMap(() =>                                                                          
        this.bookService.getBooks().pipe(                                                        
          map((books) => A.getBooksOk({ books })),                                                                                  
          catchError(() => EMPTY),
        ),                                                                                     
      ),                                                                                       
    ),                                                                                         
  );
```

However, you don't want this effect to be triggered every time you navigate to your profile page, since you only need to get the books once.

So you add `take(1)`:

```js
  getBooks$ = createEffect(() =>                                                                 
    this.actions.pipe(                                                                         
      ofType(A.getBooks),
      take(1),                                                                        
      switchMap(() =>                                                                          
        ...
```

The problem now is that if you log out and then log into another profile the store will not get your books since the effect has already been triggered by the previous profile.

The obvious solution to this would be to not use `take(1)`, and instead have another variable `booksLoaded` in the store that you can use to check if you should get the books or not.

However, this is quite tedious since you would need one of these 'loaded' variables for each variable in the store, and add a bunch of extra code to manage these variables.

So, the question is: is there a way to make an effect only trigger once (like `take(1)`), but then when you log out and back in, you allow the effect to trigger again (just once)?

**Edit**:
You could also just check if the books are undefined in the effect.
However, the effect could still be triggered multiple times before you get the response from the server, so it would not always work.

Comment: IMO the strategy of flagging if data has been loaded is a very good one, as gives you more control over the logout/login problem. In the logout action+reducer you would then clear the flag and the data would be loaded afresh for the newly logged user. It is much better than having `take(n)` in the effect which is otherwise supposed to stay alive. The flag could also be a datestamp so that you could determine if it became stale and needs refresh. Don't fret out - I think it is a good option :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you think it's a hassle just to check if you already have data. You don't need a new variable necessarily, just check if your results is already set.

```js
getBooks$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(A.getBooks),
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(S.selectBooks)),
    exhaustMap(([, books]) =>
      iif(
        () => books,
        of(A.getBooksOk({ books })),
        this.bookService.getBooks().pipe(
          map((books) => A.getBooksOk({ books })),
          catchError(() => EMPTY),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Just make sure you clear out your books in your reducer where it makes sense (like when you logout).

Comment: This wont work if "this.store.dispatch(getBooks())" is called multiple times before the data has been received from the server. Not saying that should happen often, just that this is not foolproof.

Comment: Sure the action may be initiated multiple times but it will only call `this.bookService.getBooks()` _iff_ the books in your store is not set. If the books has already been retrieved, it'll immediately return that.

Comment: We're effectively doing: `if I already have the books, then return the books, otherwise, get the books from the service` Of course this is assuming the action `A.getBooksOk` actually stores the result and is accessible in the future using the selector `S.selectBooks`.

Comment: I just reread your comment, in that case you would want to use `exhaustMap` instead of `switchMap`. As `exhaustMap` will ignore future updates until the first resolves. To continue the analogy, `if I already have the books, then return the books, otherwise, get the books from the service, but don't bug me until I know for sure`